# Incorrect mapping of mysql tinyint(2) as boolean with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dbal, tinyint, doctrine-dbal

I reverse engineered my database with symfony2 and doctrine with commands :

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

But my field was mapped as boolean instead of tinyint(2).

Why it is mapping as boolean?

Comment: I believe doctrine will map based on its unique values, so if that column only contains boolean values (ie. 1 or 0) then that is probably why it is being mapped as a boolean

Comment: @Jaitsu is there any reference for it?

Comment: Also happened to me with tinyint(3) and tinyint(4), probably also with others but I dont know :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`tinyint` (regardless of length) is mapped to type `boolean` in the [MySQL DBAL platform](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/090066c7e186a26a248344140a10ffb78a8f4186/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php#L637).

Also, consider that the entity generator is not a reliable tool: it was just meant to give you some help in getting started with larger schemas.