# Symfony 2.8 Form EntityType Returns Single Value

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

Just trying to get a select field populated from a database table. This is just a simple table with a primary key column and another column named type.

Just for testing, the example table consists of:

```
id    type
1     Sample 1
2     Sample 2
3     Sample 3
```

When I create a form:

```
$builder
       ->add('account_type', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:AppAccountTypes',
            'choice_label' => 'type'
        ));
```

My select dropdown simply repeats the first entry 3 times.

```
<select id="add_account_form_account_type" name="add_account_form[account_type]" class="form-control">
<option value="1">Sample 1</option>
<option value="1">Sample 1</option>
<option value="1">Sample 1</option>
</select>
```

For testing sake, the controller is just using:

```
$account = new Account();

$form = $this->createForm(new AddAccountForm(), $account);

return $this->render('account/new.html.twig', array(
    'page_title' => 'Create Account',
    'form' => $form->createView()
));
```

Twig template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does your controller and twig look like?

Comment: Updated, simplified everything just for testing sake. I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: Looks fine from what I can see... Probably try posting the entity and repository aswell - although I doubt it's anything obvious there

Comment: Very strange. Everything looks good. Maybe post your `AppAccountTypes.php` Entity file.

Comment: Figured it out by looking at the AppAccountTypes.php. There's a bug or feature in doctrine:mapping:import. The id column for the ap_account_types table id was using tinyint. Symfony generated an entity with a boolean instead of an integer field. This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681197/incorrect-mapping-of-mysql-tinyint2-as-boolean-with-doctrine

Answer (score 3):

May be you need to use below code:

```
$builder
   ->add('account_type', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:AppAccountTypes(Your Entity Class)',
        'mapped' => false,
        'choice_label' => 'type'
    ));
```

Because as i see in your code there is no field which name is `account_type`, May be this is the problem.

Change your controller as below:

```
$form = $this->createForm(AddAccountForm::class (Your form class), $account);
```